# How to calculate the shear centre of a wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing, ultralight, airplane

[image]

How is shear centre of a wings calculated? i.e. how can I calculate the wing shear centre of a two spar wing with main spar at 0% of wing chord and rear spar at 75% of wing chord? (Assuming the two spars have the same stiffness.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implemented a program using Matlab for S.C calculus purposes (I'm actually involved in an aircraft project and, fortunately (or not), I'm the structures guy. I have based the code and the theory in a PDF bibliography that is linked w/ the .zip folder. You'll notice two matlab codes:

-One is named "Load_Airfoil_Coordinates_using_MATLAB.m". It loads any .dat file (i.e., if you have your airfoil points, you can plot it using this code);

-Another is named "Matlab_script_for_the_shear_center.m". It calculates, beyond your airfoil's C.G (Xcg,Ycg), the shear center (Xsc,Ysc) - probably you'll need to change some of the inputs to agree with your problem, specifically. Despite I've commented the most part of this code, I recommend you to follow Perini's theory (PDF bibliography) to understand the steps.

To download the .zip folder, please click my OneDrive link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aqqj-vTtH2vbomM9cVTInsHp7dbn?e=PMFudZ.

If you're just focusing on the theory, I recommend you some bibliographic references, such as:

1. T.H.G. Megson - *Introduction to Aircraft Structural Analysis*
2. David J. Peery -  *Aircraft Structures*
3. B. K. Donaldson- *Analysis of Aircraft Structures*

   Hope I was helpful.

Best regards,
João Cioffi

Comment: Can you update the Drive link of the code? I am trying to calculate a similar thing for the wind turbine blades.
Thank you

Comment: @SushilSharma: note that "*João Cioffi was Last seen more than 3 years ago*"... Most probably you won't get any feedback from him. I'd suggest you to write a new question.